# How to select an image from internal storage and insert it in SQLite?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, gallery, storage

When the user clicks a button in my app, he has to be able to select an image from the internal storage (sd card or tablet/phone memory). Then, I want this image to be stored in a SQLite database.

So there is three questions:

- How can I show the gallery or the file explorer to the user, so he can navigate and select an image?
- How will the app know which image was selected?
- How can my app store the image in a database (BLOB data)?

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/ and also note that you can access mostly all the mesia data through MediaStore content provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, as Lingviston already pointed out. You can implement picking an image from the gallery from [**here**](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/).

As for storing the image, I'm going to edit the code in the link a little bit.

Instead of this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

I'm going to store the selected image in a `Bitmap`.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Now to store in as a `BLOB` type in android you need to convert the bitmap into bytes and then store the byte array in the sqlite database.

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
```

Now you just need to pass `imageInByte` to store in the `SQLite` database.

As a side note, both of these answers were already available all over the internet and `StackOverflow` individually, you just had to put 2 and 2 together. Please try searching thoroughly before you post a question.