# How to choose image from phone (external / internal) storage and upload to sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

I am working on an app and in the most important activity the following has to occur:

- User fills a form and selects image from his phone.
- When he clicks add data, I want to save the selected image (or it's path, anything that enables me to retrieve it later) to local database and retrieve later in other activity.

Things I have tried:

- Save image to db as blob and retrieve later as bitmap, but obviously I learned that this fails when an image larger in size is used, the blob is set to null.
- Tried getting file path of the selected image, but that file path is in a format similar to this:
  `/document/msf:35`

Then I tried to get the physical path using these SO answers: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri#answer-55469368), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath/9989900) and these answers in general: [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127139/how-to-select-an-image-from-internal-storage-and-insert-it-in-sqlite), [link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268908/access-the-phone-internal-storage-to-push-in-sqlite-database-file).

**Please don't mark this as duplicate because the solution in other answers don't work for me**

Opening intent to upload photo:

```js
// upload photo
photoActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
  public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      Intent intent = result.getData();
      if (intent.getData() == null) {
        Log.d("AddTrip", "null data from image");
      }
      Uri uri = intent.getData();
      // processing here..
    }
  }
});

}
private void uploadPhotoClicked() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("image/*");
  photoActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
}
```

Please suggest a solution to work around this and also the best practice to implement this type of functionality, I have tried using [PathUtil](https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626), but it doesn't give path for some images.

Comment: If you're using a hosting service, you may want to upload images in `File Manager` or something (in `cPanel` for example) and store the URL in DB.

Comment: I am not using a hosting service. Everything that I store is in local sqlite db.

Comment: You should save uri.toString() to database. Not uri.getPath().

Comment: And use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT instead of ACTION_GET_CONTENT so you can take persistable uri permission on uri.toString().

Answer (score 0):

As @[blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) suggested to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, I found the solution. First I recieved Uri dataString by `intent.getDataString()`, then I parsed it so I could call `takePersistableUriPermission()`.
Now I can retrieve the Uri from db and call `setImageUri(uri)`, to retrieve the image.

```
photoActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent intent = result.getData();
                    if (intent.getData() == null) {
                        Log.d("AddTrip", "null data from image");
                    }
                        image = intent.getDataString();
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(image);
                         context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                        imageName.setText(image);
                }
            }
        });

    }

 private void uploadPhotoClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        photoActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Better: Uri uri = intent.getData();